# When using useState with an array argument, how do you use useEffect to update a button dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

New to React so be gentle. I created a file uploader component and I am adding a button in App.js that is dependent on the state of the files uploaded. If there are no files uploaded, it will say "No files uploaded". If there are files uploaded it will say "Create new project". I'm using the useState hook to set my Project info:

> ```
> const [newProjectInfo, setNewProjectInfo] = useState([documents: []});
> ```

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import FileUpload from "./components/file-upload/fileUpload";
import {
  //Custom components created with styled-components
  UploadToProjectContainer,
  CreateNewProjectBtn,
  NoFilesSelectedBtn
} from "./components/file-upload/fileUploadStyles";

function App() {

  const [newProjectInfo, setNewProjectInfo] = useState({
    documents: []
  });

  const updateUploadedFiles = (files) =>
    setNewProjectInfo({ ...newProjectInfo, documents: files});

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    //add logic to create a new project
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      >
        <FileUpload
          accept=".jpg,.png,.jpeg,.pdf,.doc,.gif,.bmp,.tiff,.svg,.dwg,.docx,.eps,.exe"
          label="File(s)"
          multiple
          updateFilesCb={updateUploadedFiles}
        />
        <UploadToProjectContainer>
          <button>
            Create New Project.
          </button>
        </UploadToProjectContainer>

      </form>
    </div>
  );

}


export default App;
```

As you can see, right now there is a static "Create New Project" button. I created styled containers for each of the buttons I want to render dynamically (see: `CreateNewProjectBtn` & `NoFilesSelectedBtn`), but I cannot access the props of the state to change the button when a file is uploaded. I know I have to use useEffect but the `document[]` prop of `newProjectInfo` is inaccessible - but that is what is being updated. Hopefully this was clear. Please let me know if I need to clarify.

Comment: Instead of having separate button components it would be easier to have _one_ generic button component into which you can pass some props, like the name, and a handler.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite following what you are saying is an issue. Are you saying that the `updateUploadedFiles` callback isn't updating the state correctly as you expect?

Comment: @DrewReese updateUploadedFiles is updating the state correctly. I want to use the event of the documents property updating to trigger a change in my dynamic button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see, you want to conditionally render different button text based on the `newProjectInfo.documents` array being populated or not. Use a ternary operator to check if the `newProjectInfo.documents` array has a truthy `length` (*non-zero*) property to conditionally render one string or the other.

No need to use an `useEffect` for this, updating the state will trigger a rerender. Just compute the displayed button text per render cycle.

Example:

```
<button>
  {newProjectInfo.documents.length ? "No files uploaded" : "Create New Project"}
</button>
```

Comment: The state is not defined. It is within the 'hooks' prop value.

Comment: @deputy_danger Oh, sorry, I said state, but meant specifically the `newProjectInfo` state.

Comment: Thank you! The logic is backwards but otherwise it worked. Thanks so much

Comment: @deputy_danger Ah, again, sorry, that *should* read as "if newProjectInfo.documents array is populated render 'Create New Project' else render 'No files uploaded'". Sorry for any confusion on my part, I actually had it what I thought was reversed originally. Reverting it back.